# WPF Add indentation before TreeViewItem template

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview, treeviewitem

I am developing a WPF application and I'm struggling with TreeView. I want to achieve look like in Windows Explorer.
[image]

The default TreeView style stretches the TreeViewItem only for the required space.

[image]

I have overridden the default template to achieve this look, but I really cannot figure out how to add the space on left of child items.
[image]

My code:

```xaml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition/>
      </Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <Border x:Name="Bd" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
         <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
               <ColumnDefinition MinWidth="19" Width="Auto"/>
               <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
               <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
               <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" Grid.Column="1" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
            <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Grid.Column="0" ClickMode="Press" IsChecked="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}"/>
         </Grid>
      </Border>
      <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" />
   </Grid>
```

Comment: You forgot to add `<ColumnDefinition Width="INDENTATION"/>` to the first grid so ItemsPresenter with Grid.Column="1" will be put in the first column

Answer (score 0):

Your `Style` got some flaws.
You are missing a column (that's why the items are positioned below the header). Your `ItemsPresenter` is visible all the time. It should be collapsed and become visible only when the expander is pressed. You are missing a corresponding trigger. Also you need to hide the expaner for items that don't have children.

This how the basic `Style` should look like.
To change the indetion, just add a `Margin` to the `ItemPresenter`.

```
<Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Grid SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition />
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

          <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" 
                        Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                        ClickMode="Press"
                        IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=IsExpanded}"
                        Style="{StaticResource ExpandCollapseToggleStyle}" />
          <Border x:Name="Bd" 
                  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">

            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                              ContentSource="Header"
                              HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" />
          </Border>

          <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" 
                          Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1"
                          Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </Grid>
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                   Value="false">
            <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Hidden" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                   Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost"
                    Property="Visibility"
                    Value="Visible" />
          </Trigger>
          <Trigger Property="IsSelected"
                   Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="CornflowerBlue" />
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: But then the Item does not expand to full parent [length](https://imgur.com/a/Eq5p3pq) like in the windows explorer in question does

Comment: What do you mean? The items will stretch to occupy available horizontal space. How do you set the selected item background?

Comment: I have added a corresponding `IsSelected` trigger to set the background of the selected item. Using the above code the item does stretch as expected.